# How to export, QTextToSpeech( any Qt classes) to QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have written,     `qmlRegisterType<QTextToSpeech>("com.company.Speech" , 1, 0, "TextToSpeech");`

But I know, I can not access, public methods of QTextToSpeech class, since API is not known to the meta object compiler. Can Some one help me to resolve this issue. I mean is it OK to use below approach ?

```
class TextToSpeech: public QTextToSpeech
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INVOKABLE void stop(){ QTextToSpeech::stop();}
};
```

I am not sure, whether above approach is optimum or not. Since every public method explicitly need to written,  Does Qt provides any other quick solution( script/any ), so that existing Qt class can directly export to qml with ease registration ?

Comment: it is not necessary to override "stop" with a Q_INVOKABLE since "stop" is a slot that is accessible from QML

Comment: OK. It means need to override all public functions. Thanks for the update.

Comment: No, on the contrary. If you analyze the classes you will see that almost all of them are qproperties, qsignals or qslots so they can be used directly in QML